# Finding all classes that implement an Abstract class in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, abstract-class

In Visual studio, is it possible to find what classes implement an `abstract` class?

For instance, i'm looking at the `abstract` class `System.Windows.Media.Brush`, and would like to know what classes (ideally just those that are part of the Microsoft stack) implement it.

Failing that, is there a reflector that will do the job?

Comment: Download JetBrains .NetPeek, you can sneak into the .net frameworks and find what you want. That's a pretty nice software by the way.

Comment: Not in VS but [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.brush.aspx) has the info.